# RealM: How to remove RealmList but check references

Tags: android, realm

I have RealmList in the RealmObject and some other RealmObjects. I want to clear list and remove objects from RealM BUT if some other object has reference on this object(that is in the RealmList) I want just clear references and keep it in RealM.

I didn't find method for such deleting, is there any easy way?

Answer (score 3):

RealmList has two methods for removing objects from it:

- `RealmList.remove(index)/RealmList.clear()` removes items only from the list, but doesn't delete them from the Realm.
- `RealmList.deleteFromRealm()/RealmList.deleteAllFromRealm()` removes items from both the list and Realm.

So, if you just use `remove()/clear()` it should work the way you want. You see the methods in our API docs here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html

Comment: no, actually I want deleteFromRealm only if there are no any references on this object(object in list). If I use deleteFromRealm() it remove object despite some other objects have references on this object(that I want remove)